# Pandas to_datetime Format does nothing- python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, datetime

EDIT: Sorry guys, fixed the code and added more examples.

Trying to format dates from a xlsx file but nothing happens. Here's my code:

RAW DATA:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

df = pd.read_excel("Open_PO.xlsx")

df['Need By Date - Atual'].values
```

RAW DATA Output:

```
array(['2020-05-22T00:00:00.000000000', '2020-06-03T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2020-06-03T00:00:00.000000000', ...,
       '2022-10-28T00:00:00.000000000', '2022-10-28T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2022-12-22T00:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

FORMATTING ATTEMPT:

```
df['Need By Date - Atual'] = pd.to_datetime(df["Need By Date - Atual"],format = '%d-%b-%y').dt.date

df['Need By Date - Atual'].values
```

OUTPUT:

```
array([datetime.date(2020, 5, 22), datetime.date(2020, 6, 3),
       datetime.date(2020, 6, 3), ..., datetime.date(2022, 10, 28),
       datetime.date(2022, 10, 28), datetime.date(2022, 12, 22)],
      dtype=object)
```

As you can see, the format paramater doesnt work.

Already tried adding dayfirst=True, astype function, and pretty much everything people posted in other questions.

Cant use the date in str format because it messes up the sort_values function I use later in the code.

What can I do??

Comment: work out a minimal working example of what you want to do in 2 lines.

Comment: `df['Need By Date - Atual']` is already of dtype datetime, no need to call `pd.to_datetime`. If you e.g want to cast to string you could do so by `df['Need By Date - Atual'].dt.strftime('%d-%b-%y')`

Comment: `format` is only used if the type is a `str`, as you are converting from `datetime64[ns]` it doesn't consider it.

Comment: @AmyChodorowski, to be precise: in this context, `format` is a keyword argument of `pd.to_datetime` that specifies a strptime directive. You're right that one only needs it if the *input* is of datatype string (not datetime). But since dtype is already datetime, it's not *wrong*; more like *not applicable*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Pandas Series are not numpy arrays

This line already did exactly what you wanted:

```
df['Need By Date - Atual'] = pd.to_datetime(df["Need By Date - Atual"],format = '%d-%b-%y').dt.date
# -> type pandas.Series
```

But this line shows you a numpy array from your pandas Series:

```
df['Need By Date - Atual'].values 
# -> type numpy.ndarray
```

Since Series and formatted datetimes are specific to pandas, the values will be casted into regular datetimes, known by numpy.

## How to have the result as strings

This is probably what you wanted to achieve :

```
pd.to_datetime(dd[0]).dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y").values
```

This time (no pun intedned), the visual format will be applied as strings, no as datetime.

## How to format datetimes for excel

You probably want to use the argument `date_format` from pandas.ExcelWriter:

```
with ExcelWriter('path_to_file.xlsx', date_format='DD-MM-YY') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='some_date_sheet')
```

Source: [pandas' ExcelWriter documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html)

Comment: Damn, didnt know that, thanks!

The problem is, when I use the xlsx writer to create a xlsx file using the clean dataframe, the date output is the same as in the numpy array.

Is there anything I can do to format it correctly?